# i want easy tutorial website for studying about images in java?

Tags: java, image

Any one help me.. Send me the link of image tutorial of java?

Comment: Image processing in Java is actually pretty darn straightforward: see javax.imageio.ImageIO.read().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you started with the [official Java documentation on the subject](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)?